# Openpyxl Python - How to iterate through large file and return values in specific columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am quite new to programming and am using openpyxl to return some values from a spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet is large and contains about 90,000 rows and 50 columns.

I've created a simplified version of the problem in the image below with just a few rows:

[Excel Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEST8.png)

What I am trying to do is iterate through all the rows in the spreadsheet and where column B = "Y", take the corresponding value of the cell in the column "code" and perform a function with that code.

I've been trying to use sheet.iter_rows but not had much luck and have had some really slow performance.

```
for y_row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=4, min_col=2, max_col=4):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == "Y"
```

How do I get cell.value to refer specifically to column 2?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use just `y_row[1].value == 'Y' ` for the cell in column 2 of the current row (if you count columns from 1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, both answers really helped me work out how to refer to the specific column in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ckecked = 2
code = 4

for y_row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=4, min_col=2, max_col=4):
    if y_row[checked-1].value == "Y":
        myfunc( y_row[code-1].value )
```

Comment: Apologies, quite new to this. I've upvoted and selected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to edit the file then you can take advantage of read-only mode. This will load the file much faster.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename_and_path, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
# Only look at cells in column B
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2):
    if row[0].value:
        # code body.
```